# Display all posts by a single user in RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am pretty new to rails and I am trying to display all the posts made by a user in my app.I did go through similar posts in this forum but did not succeed. I did some scaffolding with name , title and content attributes and then created a model called Blogger with 'name' attribute.

Here's my code

Controller

```
class BloggersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @blogger = blogger.find(params[:id])
    @title = @blogger.name
    @posts = @blogger.posts
    respond_with(@posts)
  end
end
```

View

```
Index.html.erb

<% @blogger.post.each do |post| %>
  post.name
  # Comments to the Post
  post.comments.each do |comment|
    comment.comments
 <% end %>
```

Model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, :presence=>true
  validates :title, :presence=>true
  has_many :comments
  belongs_to :blogger
  belongs_to :topic,    :touch => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :blogger
  attr_accessible :name, :title, :content
end
```

I ma getting a "NoMethodError in Posts#index" error which says

undefined method `post' for nil:NilClass and has the code for index.htm.erb in the extracted source

Comment: What is in you `Blogger` class? Quite important since you try to approach the posts from this model :>

Comment: a String called "name" for the blogger. every blogger can create multiple posts. I wish to list down all the posts made by a blogger when i click on its name. appreciate your help

Comment: Your entire class `Blogger` is a single string called `name`? Not sure that's quite right, since you reference `blogger.name` and `blogger.posts`.

Answer (score 2):

**not the answer, but just a few guidelines:**

there are a lot of errors in your questions code.

```
@blogger = blogger.find(params[:id])
```

i think it should be changed to

```
@blogger = Blogger.find(params[:id])
```

at next make a

```
raise @blogger.inspect
```

and see if its loaded.

and in your view you can do better this:
(btw: it needs to be called show.html.erb not index.html.erb if you have the show method)

```
#show html.erb

<%=render @blogger.posts %>
```

and then you make a file in posts/_post.html.erb

```
<%= post.name %>
<%= render post.comments %>
```

and a file `comments/_comment.html.erb` where you render the comment.

this is rails way to be DRY!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you put this code in index.html.erb
So, when you try to display this HTML page, rails will try to call the method index in the controller, but you don't have any method called index.
Try to put this code in a method called index / or try to change the name of your html.erb file to show.html.erb

EDIT : So, in your code you pass the @posts variable but in your view you called @blogger.post.
It is not supposed to be resolved. You have to choose between passing @blogger or @posts to your view, and only use attributes of the variable you passed to the view.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are looking for is a simple typo, in your view you should write

```
@blogger.posts.each
```

instead of

```
@blogger.post.each
```

Hope this helps.